# git push --force to remote server fails

Tags: git, github

i'm trying to push local changes:

```
git push all
```

"all" means repo on github and remote server - in my .git/config:

```
[remote "all"]
    url = git@github.com:...myrepo.git
    url = ssh://usrname@servername/myrepo.git/
```

originally it was presumed that nothing should be changed manually on server, but eventually it did happen. however the changes on the server are insubstantial, and i want to override them to have an exact replica of my local repo. so, now i can't push to the remote server obtaining an error:

```
remote: error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
remote: Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
```

i am aware of previous answers to similar question, but unfortunately "git push origin --force all" doesn't work, throwing the same error

please, help! thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it makes perfect sense then. Your remote on your network is not bare. Ie, you work on it; it has it's own working directory. In fact the branch you are trying to push to is currently checked out. To add, you also have some modifications that are not committed yet. Git will refuse to zap your changes over there.

The proper workflow is to pull the changes from there on the remote.

However, you can also

- get to a headless state by checking out a particular commit, not a branch, on the remote repo.
- make it a bare repository, if it truly is a central one where others are going to use it or a CI server is going to query it. This is done with `git clone --bare`.

Comment: btw, i decided to make it clean again, so, i did `git clone --bare` from github. everything seemed fine until the following push to appsrv surprised me with this: "cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied". should i give write access to .git? i don't think it is ok.. besides, i haven't done it before, and it wasn't a problem..

Comment: this will be taken care of by allowing write permissions to the user that you are logged in as on the other computer.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the man page for [push](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-push).

You can't have multiple repos represented by one remote. Add "github" and "network" as separate remotes. In your last example of push, "all" is treated as a branch name!.

The syntax is `git push remote-name branch-name:remote-branch-name` where `remote-branch-name` is implied if it and the colon are omitted.

You would then use the `--all` option to the push command to push to both github and network remotes.

```
git push --all
```

would make sense after you set up separate remotes for all the places you want to push to.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but unfortunately it didn't work (( i get the same error: "Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten..."

Comment: did you add the 2 remotes and remove the "all" remote? does `git push github somebranch` work?

Comment: Yes, i do have 2 separate [remotes] in config: `[remote "github"]` and `[remote "appsrv"]`, and i removed `[remote "all"]`. There's only one branch at the moment, so `git push github` works perfectly (well, `git push github master`, too). But `git push -f appsrv` (or `git push --all`) throwing that error.